# Change remote directory after connecting via ssh

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew, ssh

I want to make a ssh-config, that automatically changes the folder after connecting. I heart of a possibility in the linux universe with the configuration in ssh-config-file. Something like this:

```
RemoteCommand cd /var/www/html/project-directory
```

Because of multiple projects on the same server I want to make different ssh-configs with only different of RemoteCommand to get into the right projectfolder.

```
ssh project-x
```

I tried this:

```
RemoteCommand cd /var/www/html/project-x
```

here I login, got the MOTD and get loged out directly.

and that:

```
RemoteCommand cd /var/www/html/project-x && exec bash --login
```

here I login, got the MOTD and freeze on this position.

My whole config looks like this:

```
Host customer
    User username
    Hostname project-x.example
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_project-x
    RemoteCommand cd /var/www/html/project-x && exec bash --login
    #RemoteCommand cd /var/www/html/project-x
```

Is there a way to use RemoteCommand to change directories after login on apple terminal. I use `/usr/local/bin/bash` from Homebrew: `/usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.0.11/bin/bash` (not the zshell).

Comment: The shell that matters is what runs on the servers - what is it?

Comment: You have two RemoteCommand lines up there, which one is the one you've tried? Also `cd ... && exec bash --login` is pointless, the newly spawned bash will always start with the home directory of the user.

Comment: which bash (server) > /usr/bin/bash // how can I find out which bash that is?

Comment: I updated my question @nohillside